# Wordpress - Publish post with featured image at same time via PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I am publishing to Wordpress via PHP, as follows.

- Create post with *wp_insert_post()*
- Add Featured Image with *wp_insert_attachment()*

**Problem**:

When creating the Post, there is a Plugin *(SNAP autoposter)* that will automatically publish it on Facebook. But, as obvious, it does not wait until the featured image is attached.

**Question**:

How should I proceed to publish the post with an already assigned attachment?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't publish the post until the attachment has been added.

- Set the `post_status` to `draft` when you call `wp_insert_post`.
- Add the attachment to the draft.
- Use `wp_publish_post` to publish the post.

If the plugin is setup correctly, it will be listening for the status transition to publish.